# Get data from a complex string with Regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a requirement to get required data from a complex string as below:

1) (99)00614141414167890(20)13132324(10)12423352(50)465654(30)96(37)6

2) (20)13132324(10)12423352(50)465654(30)96(37)6

Requirement:
1) Get the number after the code (99)from (string 1) 
   Expected answer will be : 00614141414167890

2) Get the string of number after Code(20) and code(10) from string (2)

Expected answer: 13132324 + 12423352

Can this be done using regular expression?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Can you add some more words describing what you want to see in your variables after 1) and 2) ? For example, edit your post so it says: "Requirement. 1) Get the number after the code (99)from (string 1), giving a result of `00614141414167890(20)13132324(10)12423352(50)465654(30)96(37)6` " etc

Answer (score 0):

It all depends whether string after AI is of fixed size or of variable length, whether AI and value after that is optional or not.

Below is an example for (20)13132324(10)12423352(50)465654(30)96(37)6. You should be able to adjust it for your purposes. Note I haven't tested it.

```
string pattern = @"(20)([0-9]{8})(10)([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})(50)([0-9]{6})(30)([0-9]{2})(37)([0-9]{1})";
var match = Regex.Match( yourBarcode, pattern );
if ( match != null && match.Groups.Count == 11 )
{
    // examples: 
    // barcode: "(20)13132324(10)12423352(50)465654(30)96(37)6" 
    // 20firstCode10secondCode50thrirdCode30fourthCode37lastDigit
    // match.Groups[ 0 ].Value - whole barcode
    // "20131323241012423352504656543096376"
    // match.Groups[ 1 ].Value - AI(20)
    // "20"
    // match.Groups[ 2 ].Value - firstCode
    // "13132324"
    // match.Groups[ 3 ].Value - AI(10)
    // "10"
    // match.Groups[ 4 ].Value - secondCode
    // "12423352"
    // match.Groups[ 5 ].Value - AI(50)
    // "50"
    // match.Groups[ 6 ].Value - thirdCode
    // "465654"
    // match.Groups[ 7 ].Value - AI(30)
    // "30"
    // match.Groups[ 8 ].Value - fourthCode
    // "96"
    // match.Groups[ 9 ].Value - AI(37)
    // "37"
    // match.Groups[ 10 ].Value - lastDigit
    // "6"
    string code20 = match.Groups[ 2 ].Value;
    string code10 = match.Groups[ 4 ].Value;
}
```

In the example I've assumed all values after AIs are of fixed size, mandatory and values for AIs = 20, 50, 30, 37 are numeric, while value for AI = 10 is alphanumeric.

Comment: Please see my latest update. If your code still work? Thanks

Comment: That's exactly what I've assumed. You have expected results in commented code. Couldn't be more clear :)

Comment: I will test it and come back here to share the result. Thanks :)